# When "Use Local IIS Web server" is on, any thrown exceptions seem to hang W3WP process

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, iis-7

At our shop, we develop on Windows Server 2008 VMs running IIS 7, same as our production web servers.  With VS2010 (and VS2008, but more so 2010), I've been having issues with debugging our ASP.NET applications.  If the application throws an exception, I'll often kill the debugger (Shift-F5) so I can correct the faulty code.  But after doing this, the process in IIS continues running, with the exception!

This leads to numerous faulty scenarios.  Sometimes the exception floats to the top at IIS, and I get a prompt asking "Would you like to debug this process in [choice of Visual Studios]" and other times there is no prompt but the debugger reattaches to the faulty process instead of starting a new one the next time I go to debug.

What am I doing wrong here?  Or what is configured wrong?  I want the workflow I had back: run web site, see exception, fix code, run web site again to verify fix.  Instead I have to manually kill W3WP in the task manager in order to continue working.

Extra info: It may also be related to the fact that the solution contains both a web site application and a web service application which the site application accesses, both running on the local IIS in two virtual directories.  Normally the attached debugger will drop into either the web site or service, if either has a problem.

Comment: Does the Web Service and the Web Application run in different application pools or the same one? Maybe the exception is occurring in one application pool while the other continues running. That would explain the behavior that you're experiencing.

Comment: We've tried them in both scenarios, and mine is currently set up with both application and service running in the same app pool.  The problem is still present.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's something else going on that is being hidden.  Can you setup Visual Studio to break on all exceptions.  From with in the IDE press CTRL + ALT + E.  That will open the Exceptions dialog.

By default, the IDE will only break on user-unhandled exceptions.  If a different exception is being thrown you might not know about it.  Add checks to each checkbox in the "Thrown" column and try running through your code another time.  If another exception is being generated, Visual Studio will break on it now.